# Where is chmod in cygwin?

Tags: cygwin

The only chmod showing up is way deep under a strange location:

```
C:\apps\OpenSSH\bin>dir /s \cygwin\chmod
 Volume in drive C is Windows7_OS
 Volume Serial Number is AC58-16CE

 Directory of C:\cygwin\usr\libexec\mc\fish

01/07/2014  02:02 AM               147 chmod
               1 File(s)            147 bytes

     Total Files Listed:
               1 File(s)            147 bytes
               0 Dir(s)  34,754,285,568 bytes free
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your command does not contain wildcards, so it will only find files called `chmod`. The corresponding cygwin program is a Windows executable though, so it is actually called `chmod.exe`:

```
C:\>dir /s /b \cygwin\chmod.*
C:\cygwin\bin\chmod.exe
C:\cygwin\lib\perl5\5.14\i686-cygwin-threads-64int\auto\POSIX\chmod.al
C:\cygwin\tmp\par-crowley\cache-exiftool-8.94\inc\lib\auto\POSIX\chmod.al
C:\cygwin\usr\share\man\man1\chmod.1.gz
```

(`/b` is just for more compact output)

Comment: Yes, doing a search for blah.exe is not natural for me.

Answer (score -1):

Or use the "which" command

```
$ which chmod
/usr/bin/chmod   % result on my install of cygwin
```